# Difference with .NET Core packages for Debug and Publish run

Tags: c#, npgsql, asp.net-core

I migrate my project to .NET Core and some things work unexpectedly:
For example - i adding package "Npgsql": "3.1.0-alpha6" and write simple

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var pgConnection = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=localhost;Port=5432;Database=*;User Id=*;Password=*;"))
        {
            pgConnection.Open();

            string sql = @"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM blog.posts";

            var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, pgConnection);

            var res = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

            Console.WriteLine(res);
        }

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

It run OK with Debug run in Visual Studio with dnx-rc1-final. 
But when I publish it - it can't run, because

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

This package used by Npgsql and when I try to generate outputs for assembly and try to compile into nuget packages - it's not working.

Why Debug run in Visual Studio find references on System.Net.Security, Version=4.0.0.0 and why published code can't do it ?

Answer (score 1):

Need add previous version of packages:

```
"System.Net.Security": "4.0.0-beta-23225",
"System.Net.NetworkInformation": "4.1.0-beta-23225"
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to copy the `System.Net.Security` dll into the `Publish` directory. You can copy it from the `Debug` directory.

Then it should work.

Both directories ar under `...\YourProject\bin\` folder

Comment: I think, that not good idea..NET Core managed by nuget packages and when i enter to packages directory - i can't find System.Net.Security build for dnxcore50

Comment: @ZOXEXIVO have you tried copying the `dll` from the `Debug` directory -- it ran with that one in the debug mode. Just give it a try...

Comment: Thank you. But copy dll is old-style

Comment: @ZOXEXIVO but it solves your problem, doesn't it? :D